# How can I add Farseer Physics Engine to a MonoGame project?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I created a MonoGame Windows Phone 8 project in Visual Studio 2013 Professional and added Farseer Physics Engine 3.5 to my solution. But when I try to add a reference to Farseer, I always get this error message:

> Unable to add the specified project reference. The reference must be a
>   Windows Phone project that targets the current or earlier version of
>   the Windows Phone OS.

What is wrong? How can I add a reference to Farseer Physics Engine?

Picture: http://s14.directupload.net/images/140501/vvux8eai.jpg

Comment: A few weeks ago I recompiled Farseer to work with MonoGame on Android and Windows as a portable class library. I don't know if there's something special about WP8 but I think it's achievable. From memory, all I had to do was update the references, add in some #if !MONOGAME defines and remove the Stopwatch class (it wasn't doing anything important).

Comment: I don't know how to update the references.

Comment: The problem is that the DLL you're trying to reference wasn't compiled to target WP8. You'll either need to find one that is, or recompile the code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following threads:

http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/discussions/490533
http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/discussions/431777

Seems that there is no real support for Farseer on W8 and WP8.